# How can I select a tab page at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

When I create a tabpage at runtime how can I call that same tabpage at a different runtime sequence?  `SelectedTab = "newPage"`? newPage is not a collection I made at design time so it's not a part of collections. newPage is created only at runtime. It's for a Windows Form program Visual studio 2010

Thanks in advance and I hope you can help.

Comment: You need to provide some sample code of how you create the tab page and what you are trying to achieve. What does "call a tabpage at a diffetrent runtime sequence mean"?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have Visual Studio installed on my system yet, waiting for IT guys....but will try for a quick pointer.

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage();
tp.Name="MyTabPage";
tabControl.Controls.Add(tp);
```

To select your tabpage, you need to refer "tp"(tabPage variable) but NOT "MyTabPage"(name of tabpage).

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
```

If they are being used in different methods or classes, try to use the properties.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Suggesting a local variable is a good way to drive the OP to despair.

Comment: I am sorry but not sure of your comment??

Comment: Hans probably means it is no good idea to create tp as a local variable somewhere. Instead, it could be a private field in the form, or eliminated altogether by referencing the tab to select by index, or ...

Comment: yes index is always a option...but if we are rearranging the order of tabpages,like creating a tabpage and inserting it in betwen the existing tabpages,may give a tough time to figure out the actual and exact index.....

Comment: btw, why local variable is not preferred...curious to know??